# i need to print the sum of counters of unread note for more than one if i have 2 or more person

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, count, sum

this code shows to me every student that do not read the notes so I need the counter of these unread to print it 
how can get the sum of all unread notes ?

```
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE parents_id='".$pid."'");
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td><b>'.$r['first_name'].'  '. $r['last_name'].'</b></td>';
echo'<td>'.$r['class_name'].'</td>';
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM notes  WHERE student_id='".$r['id']."' AND isread='0' ");
$count=mysql_fetch_array($quer);
$c=$count[0];
echo'<td><b><span style="color:red;text-align:center;">('.$c.') '.'UnRread</b></td>';
echo'<td><b>'."<a href=viewnote.php?viewnote&sid=".$r['id']."&name=".$r['first_name']."&last=".$r['last_name']."' >View</a>".'</b></td>';
echo'</tr>';
```

Comment: this query gives the count for one person if i have 2 students with different id i need the sum of unread note for both @Anant

Answer (score 0):

Keep a running total of the count:

```
$totalCount = 0;

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE parents_id='".$pid."'");
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td><b>'.$r['first_name'].'  '. $r['last_name'].'</b></td>';
echo'<td>'.$r['class_name'].'</td>';
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM notes  WHERE student_id='".$r['id']."' AND isread='0' ");
$count=mysql_fetch_array($quer);
$c=$count[0];

$totalCount = $totalCount + $c;

echo'<td><b><span style="color:red;text-align:center;">('.$c.') '.'UnRread</b></td>';
echo'<td><b>'."<a href=viewnote.php?viewnote&sid=".$r['id']."&name=".$r['first_name']."&last=".$r['last_name']."' >View</a>".'</b></td>';
echo'</tr>';
```

And after the while loop:

```
echo $totalCount;
```